# More than one step-definition method matched error in karate for match contains only step

Tags: karate, contains

Using Karate version 0.9.6.

I have a step in my feature file like this
* match final_data contains any
"""
[{"myjson": "Example"}]
"""
Running this scenario throws error orcl.feature:46 - more than one step-definition method matched: match final_data contains any - [public void com.intuit.karate.StepActions.matchDocstring(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) [final_data contains , any], public void com.intuit.karate.StepActions.match(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) [final_data , contains,  any]]

Comment: Can you please let us know what data does the `final_data` contains?

Comment: Here's the final data -         [
          {
          "name": "abcd",
          "id": '123daw'
          }
          {
          "name": "xyz",
          "id": 'dsfjskj12
          }}

Answer (score -1):

If you have the following data in the `final_data` variable, then you can use below `match` case scenario for the test case.

```
Scenario: Karate Assertion Test Case
* def final_data = [{"a": "b"}]
* match final_data contains any [{"myjson": "Example"}, {"a": "b"}]
```

Comment: Gets same error. Added final_data to my initial qn.

Comment: Also It fails only I give the docstring like this                                                         
  Scenario: Karate Assertion Test Case
    * def final_data = [{"a": "b"}]
    * match final_data contains any
  """
  [{"myjson": "Example"}, {"a": "b"}]
  """

Comment: Why have you appended `"""` with the data sets?

Comment: My json is quite big and for better readability, I used doc string